# Why are all the enemies in the Arena unarmed?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

so I just started up FEH on my device, and loaded up my cloud data. I was rank 2, and decided to enter the arena. I was below the recommended rank but I didn't care, I entered anyway. I had a low level team (about 1-5), and picked Beginner. I go in, and every enemy is unarmed! I clear it, go in again, same settings, and they're unarmed again! it's weird because this only happened on the easiest difficulty. when I did Intermediate, they had weapons. can someone explain why this happened, or was it just a glitch/bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter the arena, you are pitted against other player-created teams marked for arena defense that are around similar stats and overall skill rating as your own. Since your units were level 1 - 5, you'll be put up against a team with a very low rating. The person who set up the team you fought just removed all of their weapons. There's no real benefit to this besides providing an easy arena win. You'll see some cases where people unequip their healers so they heal instead of attack.